# base64 encoded image not dispaying in material ui CardMedia

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

hi im trying to implement material ui card component

```
 <CardMedia
                        className={classes.media}
                        title="Contemplative Reptile"
                     src={'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAtXpVp8YbaRdxnam/SvPJ/>
```

im trying to display the image in base64 encoded string format but image is not rendering

Comment: are you sure your image is correctly encoded in base64? By the way i'm not sure you can use base64 encoded images in CardMedia

Comment: yes , for privacy purpose i trimmed the message

Comment: A good alternative in my opinion is use something like <Box width={'100%'} height={100} style={{ backgroundImage: `url('data:image/jpeg;base64...")` }} />

I know, isn't the solution you were looking for but i think it's an easy way to work around it

Answer (score 10):

I just came across this problem myself and resolved it by setting the `component` prop on the `CardMedia` component to `img` and by using the `src` prop instead of the `img` prop:

```
<CardMedia component='img' src={`data:image/png;base64, ${encodedImg}`} />
```